# Backbone.js + Heap snapshot google chrome

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, google-chrome-devtools

I want to know if this is normal in a single page app

If you go to: http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/ and take some heap snapshots of adding and removing the todos  -- even if I remove all previous added todos, the memory of the heap snapshot increases every time.

[image]

Is this normal?

Should this go back to the initial value if I remove all todos?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should this go back to the initial value if I remove all todos?

Yes and no.

It should go back to it's initial value (or close) but that won't happen untill a garbage collection is actually triggered, which doesn't look like has happened in your case. You can trigger it manually under the "Timeline" tab by clicking the little trashcan icon.

Do that while recording a timeline (and check the memory checkbox) to see the heap usage drop down again.

You'll notice that the number of nodes doesn't drop all the way down to where it was when the page initially loaded and it keeps rising if you keep adding/removing todos and triggering garbage collection several times. That can be an indication a small leak and could be something to investigate further.

[image]

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I've tried clicking on that icon, but no feedback and nothing seemed to change.

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu I was doing this while recording a timeline. You could take a new snapshot after triggering GC but chances are the changes are so small they might be hard to notice. The timeline has a much better representation (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

It can be a leak or it can be that the application just caches some data structures. Also heap usage may grow as V8 will produce more code, e.g. as a result of function optimizations. Such code may survive several GC phases before it gets collected even if the function is not called any more. This is complicated and in general you shouldn't worry about that as VM should take care of that. Just keep in mind that VM may allocate some internal data structures for its own needs, they are usually collected over time. To see if JavaScript heap growth is valid you can record heap allocations timeline ("Profiles panel" > "Record Heap Allocations"). This will allow you to filter objects by allocation time and then decide if these objects should have survived or not:

[image]